# How do I create and use PL/SQL packages with python-oracledb? Getting error PLS-00905

Tags: python, database, oracle, plsql, python-oracledb

I am having difficulty using packages with python-oracledb. My code is as follows.

```
def package_basic(cur):
    cur.callproc("dbms_output.enable")
    cur.execute("""
            CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PACKAGEBASIC IS
            BEGIN
                PROCEDURE GREET(NAME VARCHAR2);
            END;
    
            CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKAGEBASIC IS
            BEGIN
                PROCEDURE GREET(NAME VARCHAR2) IS
                BEGIN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Greeting');
                END;
            END;
            """)
            
    cur.execute("""
        BEGIN
            PACKAGEBASIC.GREET('Hello');
        END;
    """)

    display_lines(cur)
```

The outcome is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelgoff/Desktop/SynergisticIT/oracledb/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    procedure2.package_basic(cur)
  File "/Users/michaelgoff/Desktop/SynergisticIT/oracledb/procedure2.py", line 86, in package_basic
    cur.execute("""
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oracledb/cursor.py", line 378, in execute
    impl.execute(self)
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/cursor.pyx", line 138, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinCursorImpl.execute
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 382, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_single_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 383, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_single_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 376, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 2, column 13:
PLS-00905: object ADMIN.PACKAGEBASIC is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 13:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The `display_lines` function gets the output from the query and puts it to the console. If I replace the `PACKAGEBASIC.GREET('Hello');` bit with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Greeting');`, it works as expected. What's the problem here?

The `cur` object is a cursor. I presume it's OK because other queries work fine.

While we're at it, is there a way to put all this into a single `execute` statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Each of your two PL/SQL CREATE statements needs to be executed in its own python-oracledb `execute()` call.  If you need an example using DBMS_OUTPUT, see https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/dbms_output.py

Comment: Why are you creating the Package spec / body every time.  Normal for everything I have worked on is to have a script to create the package / body that gets run once each time it is changed and then a separate script that contains the logic of your application that simply uses this.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I did what you suggested and it worked after that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShaunPeterson You you are right, for a project that goes beyond trying to get the syntax down, I want to separate the one-time creation of packages and the invocation of them.